# How to use GetObject in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am really new to VBScript. This is my code, which creates a text file and attaches an object to it:

```vb
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objExcel.CreateTextFile("C:\mine.txt")
```

How can I use the `getObject(Pathname,[class])` function?

Answer (score 10):

VBScript GetObject documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdccchxa(VS.85).aspx). Here is a VBScript sample:

```
Set objExcelFile = GetObject("C:\Scripts\Test.xls")
WScript.Echo objExcelFile.Name
objExcelFile.Close
```

This code will get you the Excel Workbook object contained in C:\Scripts\Test.xls. You can use TypeName() to confirm that:

```
Set objExcelFile = GetObject("C:\Scripts\Test.xls")
WScript.Echo objExcelFile.Name
WScript.Echo TypeName(objExcelFile)
objExcelFile.Close
```

The output will be:

```
test.xls
Workbook
```

If the specified Excel workbook doesn't exist the script will return an error. If an instance of Excel is already running you can use this code to get a reference to it:

```
Set objExcel = GetObject( , "Excel.Application")

For Each objWorkbook In objExcel.Workbooks
    WScript.Echo objWorkbook.Name
Next

objExcel.Quit
```

Notice the comma before 'Excel.Application'. The script gets a reference to a running Excel application, lists open workbooks names and quits Excel. If there is no Excel instance running you will receive an error. This is also why you couldn't use GetObject() to get an instance of Scripting.FileSystemObject - there was no running instance.

You could use GetObject if there is an instance og Scripting.FileSystemObject already running in memory. Try this code:

```
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFso1 = GetObject("", "Scripting.FileSystemObject")

WScript.Echo TypeName(objFso)
WScript.Echo TypeName(objFso1)
```

You can see that you first need to use CreateObject() to and when FileSystemObject is running it is possible to get a reference to it, but this doesn't make much sense because you already have a reference to it (objFso). So, use CreateObject() to create an instance of FileSystemObject.

Comment: Unless the object is single instance, if you specify a pathname (first parameter) for `GetObject` function as a zero-length string (but not omit it), the effect is similar to `CreateObject`, so `GetObject` will return a new instance of the object instead of the current instance.

Comment: As described, use VBScript's `Set objExcel = GetObject( , "Excel.Application")`. But do **NOT** use `Set objExcel = WScript.GetObject( , "Excel.Application")`, which will complain about the missing argument. I never appreciated the difference before.

Answer (score 6):

Note, that also `GetObject()` accepts  the following monikers in argument:
`"iis:<metabasepath>"` - Allows a programmer to view and alter key IIS functionality for any webserver physically connected to this machine.
`"java:<classname>"` - Returns a reference to an unregistered java object found in the %system root%\java\trustlib folder using the Java Virtual Machine.
`"script:<absolutepath>"` - Returns a reference to an unregistered Windows Scripting Component or other supported script type.
`"clsid:<clsid>"` - Returns a reference to an object by it's class ID in the registry.
`"WinMgmts:<string>"` - Allows access to base Windows OS functionality with WMI.
`"OBJREF:<base64encodedstring>"` - Returns access to a running object instance.
`"queue:<clsid/progid>"` - Used to activate a queued COM+ component via MSMQ.
`"new:<clsid/progid>"` - Allows instancing of any COM component supporting the IClassFactory pointer (including queued components).

source: http://web.archive.org/web/20021001133221/http://www.aspemporium.com/aspEmporium/tutorials/GetObject/index.asp